# Нужна ли здесь запятая перед «как»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, как

Это сложноподчинённое предложение или "знаешь как" тут какая-то единая конструкция?

*Сам знаешь(,) как здесь обращаются с неугодными.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с пропущенными, но подразумеваемыми подлежащими, и запятая перед "как" необходима.
[Ты] *Сам знаешь, как здесь* [они] *обращаются с неугодными.*

> **4.** Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится:
> 3) если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): *Я бы тоже желал знать **почему*** (Л. Т.)...

В июне у нас, **сам знаешь как**, то снежок пробросит, то выяснит с севером и стоит с неделю, то дождь. [Михаил Тарковский. Жизнь и книга // «Октябрь», 2002]
А получилось, **сам знаешь как**, ― Алексей развел руками. [Эдуард Володарский. Дневник самоубийцы (1997)]

[Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136)

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Всегда рада помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет единой конструкции. Запятая нужна.